# What is the probability of heads in unfair coin when you flip the coin ten times?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability of heads  in unfair coin when you flip the coin ten times?

i came across this question and I haven't figured it out

Suppose that you flip an unfair coin ten times, where p(heads)=3/4  and p(tails)=  1/4, Find probability of

```
1.p(no heads)

2.p(exactly 9 heads)

3.p(exactly 7 heads)

4.p(at least 7 heads)

5.p(number of heads greater than number of tails)
```

i hop this help

Thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is not a free homework solution service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the binomial distribution.

1. Probability of no heads: 
   $$\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^{10}$$
2. Exactly one head:
   $$\binom{10}{9}\,\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^9$$
3. Exactly seven heads:
   $$\binom{10}{7}\,\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^3\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^7$$
4. At least seven heads:
   $$\binom{10}{7}\,\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^3\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^7 + \binom{10}{8}\,\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^2\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^8 + \binom{10}{9}\,\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^9 + \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^{10}$$
5. Number of heads greater than number of tails:
   same idea as in the previous case but starting at 6 heads.